# How do I add tags / keywords to a windows file properties details tab using C#

Tags: file, tags, document

Ideally I would like to use the shell class to add tags to my office documents but I think the tags property is a read only item this way. Does anyone have any other ways?

There is very little on the subject. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 7):

I looked into the shellfile class a little more. The answer was staring me right in the face.

```
string[] keywords = new string[x];
var shellFile = ShellFile.FromFilePath(file);
shellFile.Properties.System.Keywords.Value = keywords;
```

to get the keywords already added to the file use:

```
var tags = (string[])shellFile.Properties.System.Keywords.ValueAsObject;
tags = tags ?? new string[0];

if (tags.Length != 0)
{
    foreach (string str in tags)
    {
        // code here
    }
}
```

and done!

Comment: When there is more than one tag in the string array need shellFile.Properties.System.Keywords.AllowSetTruncatedValue = true; before setting to avoid truncation error

Comment: When trying to write Tags using

 string[] sTags = sTagString.Split(';');
 shellFile.Properties.System.Keywords.AllowSetTruncatedValue = true;
 shellFile.Properties.System.Keywords.Value = sTags

I get error "unable to get writable property store for this property"