# C# - Add, edit and delete tags of file

Tags: c#, file, tags, filesystems, fileinfo

I would like to add and retrieve tags of files in File System.

As you can tag Stackoverflow question to the relevant topics, you can tag a file in Windows file-system:

[image: sample]

The following way doesn't give me access to the tags of the file, but only to other file properties.

```
string file = @"C:\Users\me\Desktop\MyFile.doc";

FileInfo oFileInfo = new FileInfo(file);
MessageBox.Show(oFileInfo.FullName);
```

Any ideas how to access the tags using the simple API of `System.IO`?

Comment: you didn't actually add a picture of what you want, but does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34751429/3845456) answer your question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to SET extended file properties?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337683/how-to-set-extended-file-properties)

Comment: I used TagLib for the same purpose. This question was helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68283/view-edit-id3-data-for-mp3-files

Comment: Have you resolved your problems?

Answer (score 4):

> As you can tag Stackoverflow question to the relevant topics, you can
>   tag a file in Windows file-system

This assumption is wrong. You can't add tags to all file types. See [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/add-tags-or-other-properties-to-a-file):

> Note
>
> You cannot add or modify the file properties of some types of files. 
>   For example, you can add or modify the properties of Microsoft
>   Office documents and Searches, but you can't add or modify the
>   properties of TXT or RTF files.

Besides the types mentioned there are others which can contain custom tags:

- mp3 files can contain ID3 tag of various versions
- flac and ogg files can contain ogg-vorbis tags
- jpeg files can contain exif data
- pdf files can contain various info fields

Editing/adding/removing those tags should be done with dedicated libraries.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20632612/custom-file-properties) has a nice explanation:

> In Windows Explorer you can see quite a lot of document properties for
>   many file types. The nice, unified interface suggests that there is
>   some unified property store. That's not really the case. The Explorer
>   Shell has an extensible interface for Property Sheet Handlers that
>   extract this information from various file types. There is a handler
>   for JFIF (JPEG) files, and there are handlers for OLE files (old
>   Office formats), and the new Office formats too.

And this [post shows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34736458/how-do-i-add-tags-keywords-to-a-windows-file-properties-details-tab-using-c-sh) how the OP successfully adds tags via `ShellFile`.

Also recommended reading: [Getting and Setting File Tag Meta Information in C#](http://tutorialgenius.blogspot.de/2015/03/getting-and-setting-file-tag-meta.html)