# accessing file details in c#

Tags: c#, filesystems

When you right click on a file in a folder in your PC, and go to properties in the dropdown menu, a dialog box pops up. One of the tabs on that box is details.

Is there a way to access those details in code? I've tried using files, directories, FileInfo, FileVersionInfo and I can't seem to figure out how to, and even if they are accessible. I am uploading images from a local repository folder and need some of those details to add as metadata in the blob for storage in Azure Storage.

```
var info = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(@"C:\\mypath\\GE_StrengthenedFrame.JPG");
```

that does not produce any methods to access properties, for example an image will have properties such as Camera and Image and sub properties to those main properties.

Comment: Show what you have tried...FileInfo and FileVersionInfo give you most of what you need. Which part are you missing?

Comment: Some info is in FileInfo but type specific data must be read either from other sources like properties of the Image once you have loaded it: in addition to the dimensions and resolution there are PropertyItems and/or Exif data, if they are present. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37789372/c-sharp-add-edit-and-delete-tags-of-file/37844828#37844828) for a discussion. For easiest access you may want to seach for a library, but, please not here..

Comment: @Rufus...see updated OP

Comment: Meta data is harder to get from c#.  I assume you are looking for the data you see when you hover over the Windows Explorer.  See posting : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37869388/how-to-read-extended-file-properties-file-metadata

Comment: @jdweng...looks good. Ill test that out later

Comment: You probably should be asking about image metadata instead of filesystem data. If you think in those terms you will find articles like [How to: Read Image Metadata](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xddt0dz7(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I used an image file as an example, I need the details for all kinds of files